# goto difficulties with C#

Tags: c#, goto

Why do I get the following compiler error:

> //error CS0159: No such label 'lbl_proc_20'

with the following code:

```
//JUST A DUMMY CODE TO ILLUSTRATE THE CONCEPT
int a = resultOfFunction1();
int b = resultOfFunction2();

//10+ Local variables that are calculated depending on the results above

if (a < 10)
{
    switch (b)
    {
        case 0:
            //Actions for A<10, B=0, using local variables
            break;
        case 1:
            double c = someFunction(a, b);  //In real code involves calculations based on a and b
            if(c > 10.0)
                goto lbl_proc_20;   //error CS0159: No such label 'lbl_proc_20' within the scope of the goto statement

                    //Actions for A<10, B=1, using local variables
            break;
        default:
            //Actions for A<10, B=Other, using local variables
            break;
    }
}
else if (a < 20)
{
lbl_proc_20:
    switch(b)
    {
        case 0:
            //Actions for A<20, B=0, using local variables
            break;
        case 1:
            //Actions for A<20, B=1, using local variables
            break;
        case 2:
            //Actions for A<20, B=2, using local variables
            break;
        default:
            //Actions for A<20, B=Other, using local variables
            break;
    }
}
else if (a < 30)
{
    switch(b)
    {
        case 0:
            //Actions for A<30, B=0, using local variables
            break;
        case 1:
            //Actions for A<30, B=1, using local variables
            break;
        case 2:
            //Actions for A<30, B=2, using local variables
            break;
        default:
            //Actions for A<30, B=Other, using local variables
            break;
    }
}
```

Why am I getting an error for a goto statement and how to make it work?

**EDIT:** Changed the sample to illustrate the actual code.

Comment: 'goto' must be a new f'word in programming circles, hah :D

Comment: @user843732 - Yes, for over 30 years. With good reasons and not just by Microsoft.

Comment: @user843732 I would recommend reworking your code. There are only, very very very special cases where goto might be a choice.

Answer (score 10):

You can only use `goto` to jump to labels within the scope of the `goto`. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hak1fc9d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that describes error `CS0159`:

> The label referenced by the goto statement could not be found **within the scope** of the goto statement.

Although the label exists, you can't jump out of an `if` block into an `else` block. The code within `else` is not the same scope as that that contains the `goto`.

It's time to restructure your code so it doesn't need `goto`.

**Edit**

You should try to simplify your logic. Multiple functions are preferable to `goto` statements.

One option you might want to consider is [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489441.aspx). It's a really neat tool that lets you represent your logic visually as a flow chart. WWF will then generate the code necessary to handle the logic you specify. This might work for since it appears like you are creating some type of finite state machine or similar process.

Comment: You want to show me how you'd restructure it without making a 10-function monster out of it? The code I posted is a diagram of an actual code I have. PS. Note that each 'switch' statement has 3 to 4 'case's and there're about 10 outer 'if's in a real code.

Comment: @user843732: Not without knowing what your code is actually supposed to do.

Comment: @user843732: Ok, I've added another option. Check out [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489441.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. But come one, all that so that not to use "goto" :)))))))

Comment: It's not just the goto. The multiple `switches` and `if`s that you mentioned will make the code unmanageable. WWF, on the other hand, lets you design your logic in a nice friendly drag-and-drop interface. Don't give up yet - try WWF! :)

Comment: Yes, maybe in the future. Right now I'm looking for a solution to make my existing code work.... without learning new programming techniques.

Answer (score 2):

As a response to "How to do it without goto"

```
bool pretendA20 = false;

if (a < 10)
{
    switch (b)
    {
        case 0:
            //Actions for A<10, B=0, using local variables
            break;
        case 1:
            double c = someFunction(a, b);  //In real code involves calculations based on a and b
            if(c > 10.0)
            {
                //goto lbl_proc_20;   
                pretendA20 = true;
                break;
             }

             //Actions for A<10, B=1, using local variables

            break;
        default:
            //Actions for A<10, B=Other, using local variables
            break;
    }
}

if ((a >= 10 && a < 20) || pretendA20)
{
//lbl_proc_20:
    switch(b)
    {
```

Comment: All your 'if's, 'and's and 'pretend's will make my actual code totally unreadable. But, I guess, you'll stick with your opinion and I'll stick with mine... So far, I haven't heard a single argument over why 'goto' is bad. I understand that MS C# compiler fails to check variable scope with the use of 'goto', but that doesn't justify the "badness" of 'goto'. It simply means inability of MS to make good products. This whole thread was just one big name-calling, and an attempt to make my proposed code "more unreadable"...

Answer (score 1):

The C# language specification (chapter 8 on page 249) states:

> If a label with the given name does not exist in the current function
>   member, or if the goto statement is not within the scope of the label,
>   a compile-time error occurs. This rule permits the use of a goto
>   statement to transfer control out of a nested scope, but not into a
>   nested scope.

In your case the label `lbl_proc_20` is not in the same scope as the `goto` and you're trying to transfer control into another nested scope.

You can grab the language spec from here:

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029

Comment: Yes, thank you. I got that. What I guess, I'm asking, is how to rewrite this with the least of involvement since 'goto' seems to be deemed bad by Microsoft (and everyone here took it as a gospel)?

Comment: @Kev A title of a question does not always clearly represent its content in full context.  The question had to do with how to optimize the IL code of .NET, either by writing better code as was my solution or by using a bytecode optimizer.  The "issue" of the question was not to shop but rather to find a solution to my technical problem about IL code.  Questions do not necessarily fully equate to the issue.  Stackoverflow is about solving issues.  Sorry about the bad choice of words on my part and I understand your position, but find it based on preconceptions.  I apologize for the cud slang.

Comment: @zezba9000 - apologies accepted. I would advise asking about this on [meta] rather than discussing in the comments here. Thanks.