# I cant fix the "No Such Label 'name' within the scope of the goto statement"

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in c# and when I was creating this program called "X" I got an error called "No Such 'name' within the scope of the goto statement" can you guys help me I'm super confused and I want this to be the second program I actually publish, my first being a stupid little calculator thank you and goodbye.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Password
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start:
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Welcome to X, The application with options because why not");
            Console.WriteLine("Whats The password?");
            string Pass = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            if (Pass == "80085")
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("W-What the heck T-That command overrided 
    mmy... Welcome to X, Shawn");
                Console.WriteLine("Press a key to countinue, Shawn");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose a options for X");
                Console.WriteLine("Press a key to countinue, Shawn");
                Console.ReadLine();

                Commands:
                Console.WriteLine("IF you dont know how to use this, \njust type Credits for credits \nGTS to go back to the start \nExit to well exit\n And Help for well help");

            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect, Please use a vaild password");
                Console.WriteLine("Press a key to Clear and go back to start");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                goto Start;


            }

            string Cho = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            if (Cho == "Credits")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Credits:\n Shawn");
                Console.WriteLine("Press a key to Clear and go back to commands");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                goto Commands;

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: goto statement should be in the same scope of label. In your example they are not in the same scope

Comment: Possible duplicate of [goto difficulties with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665530/goto-difficulties-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Commands` label is defined inside an IF block so it's not reachable outside of that block. Furthermore try to avoid using `goto` in C# programs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is scope, first and foremost.

However i think the real problem and the real answer is **don't use `goto`**.

There are very few reasons to use it in modern languages, it makes your code visually unpredictable and there are very few places i can ever remember that it makes your methods more readable.

There are exceptions to this, we could debate until the cows-come-home, however none of them represent what you are trying to do.

- If you need to loop use a `while`
- If you need to continue the loop without further processing use `continue`
- If you need to encapsulate logic use a method or a local method.
- If you need to branch, use an `If`